# Making perpetual motion machine from candy-sharing cats

Tags: puzzle

It is well known that cats can be turned into perpetual motion machines under the right circumstances. Candy-sharing cats are such wonderful creatures that come in infinite supplies, labeled 1,2,3,...

An $M$ machine is made by the set of cats $\{1,2,3,...,M\}$ sitting in a circle, in any order, along with any distribution of candies among them.

1. For any $n$, if cat $n$ has $n$ candies, it will share them by giving each cat in its clockwise direction one candy, until it runs out of candies or every other cat has got one from it.
2. When one cat has finished the sharing, if there's another cat who qualifies for condition 1, it will repeat that process.
3. If more than one cat qualifies for condition 1, the one with the smallest number will share.

**If we can make an $$ machine in which there's always a next sharer, the candies will never stop flowing, then it's an $$ perpetual motion machine (M-PMM)!**

An example of a 4-PMM is cat order $3,1,2,4$ and candy distribution $1,0,0,4$. It undergoes 6 sharings in a loop:

> $3124$

> $1004\\2111\\2021\\3002\\0113\\0023\\1004$

**Question: Is there an upper limit to the size of a PMM?**

---

Source & progress: I found the prototype of the puzzle in [an obscure corner of the web](https://tieba.baidu.com/p/6164132157?pn=6), made some natural generalizations, and shared it on [puzzling.stackexchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120811/making-perpetual-motion-machine-from-candy-sharing-cats). We know 2,4,6,8-PMM exist, and 3,5,7-PMM don't. 10-PMM probably doesn't exist either, according to [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/120842/68538).

Comment: Fantastic riddle, thanks Eric for sharing it!!

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen You're welcome, Dominic! The current known results are obtained more or less by brute force search, which becomes infeasible for more than 10 cats.

Comment: Is the condition in step 1 that cat $n$ has *exactly* or *at least* $n$?

Comment: Amusing name for the puzzle, although to justify it, you really should say that you're working with sets of immortal cats. :) In more prosaic terms, if I've understood correctly, you've described an algorithm and are calling it a "perpetual motion machine" for a certain input if the algorithm never terminates. Since there are many algorithms for which this is an interesting question, you might add some modifiers to your abbreviation, e.g., CSCPMM (Candy Sharing Cats Perpetual Motion Machine).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Exactly.

Comment: @JoeSilverman Joe, when you encounter cats who share candies among themselves, you know you've met no mortals!  

"Since there are many algorithms for which this is an interesting question" Are you referring to cats sharing candies using different rules (algorithms) by this claim? I wonder why should many general questions about these algorithms be interesting/difficult. What do they have in common?

Comment: That was a dichotomy. If it's "*exactly*" then that creates a lot of blocking states and may simplify the analysis; if it's "*at least*" then I would be inclined to consider whether a starting state assigning $n^3$ to each of them would work.

Comment: What if the average number of candies exceeds the number of cats?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson  What do you mean by the average number of candies?

Comment: @Eric, so that at least one among the n cats, at least one always has at least n candies.

Comment: There are definitely 10-PPMs. In fact, [here's an exhaustive list of all PPMs with M<11](https://pastebin.com/ZMV5NYz2).

Comment: Just finished a computer search, there are no 11-PPMs

Comment: @AnttiP  Thanks, this really seems to suggest that PMMs exist when M is even. Did you use any tricks to speed up the search?

Comment: @Anttan A suggestion towards finding large PPMs: the number of total candies in a PPM seems to hover around $M(M+1)/4$ (floor). Can you try searching for this number of candies?

Comment: For each permutation I only considered initial candy distributions where cat #M shares (thus for each permutation there are only (M-1)! possible distributions). Also I used bitwise operations and multi-threading but it still took 12 hours. I have some ideas on how to prune the search space further. For example it seems that cats #M and #M-1 can always be swapped, though I have no idea why this is the case. Also permutations like 354789612 can be discarded because if cat #3 receives a candy then cat #5 also gets one which implies that cat #5 will eventually have 6 candies.

Comment: @AnttiP   Surprisingly, there exists a 13-pmm. Check the new answer in the puzzling-stackexchange link at the end of the question.